# How do I change the datepicker format flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

[image]

How do I change the format of the date? I am using a datepicker to pick a date but I want the date to display as dd/mm/yyyy, here is the code

```
class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatePicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<DatePicker> createState() => _DatePickerState();
}
class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
            onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
            child: Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0])),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying the date you should use this

```
Text("${selectedDate.day}/${selectedDate.month}/${selectedDate.year}"),
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using instead of

```
child: Text("${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0])),
```

do

```
child: Text(DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(selectedDate)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var formattedSelectedDate;

if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
  setState(() {
       final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
       final String formatted = formatter.format(picked);
       print(formatted); 
       selectedDate = picked;           
       formattedSelectedDate = formatted;

  });
}
```

Use this "formattedSelectedDate" to display on the UI.

Comment: this won't work. selectedData is of type `DateTime` and you are trying to assign a `String` to it

Comment: Check now i just updated the code